# To add an SVG image on Here-maps

Tags: java, android, svg, here-api

I have tried adding a resource-based XML(SVG Supported) onto HERE Maps using `mapMarker`, as per my knowledge it considers only a .png, if a resource-based XML like below is given, nothing is displayed on the map:

```java
Image img = new Image();
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_gradientwithcorners);
mapMarker = new MapMarker(new GeoCoordinate(mSharedViewModel.getPreviewDestinations().getValue().get(0).getDestinationCoordinate()), img);
mMap.addMapObject(mapMarker);
```

Is there any way to achieve the same.

Also the below exception is thrown:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Image provided is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Currently, SVG is not supported as MapMarker image object. 
An Image object can only be created with BMP, JPEG, and PNG data formats.

See MapMarker Image class description:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/index.html